# The Kafka stream problem about suppress() method

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to use `windowby()` and `count()` methods to get request count, then display the data after `toStream()` method.

```
 source.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .grace(Duration.ZERO))
        .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
        .toStream()
        .foreach((k, v) -> log.info("dataStream k: {} v: {}", k.key(), v));
```

I found if I input record continually, data can stream to `foreach()` method normally. But when I stopped input record and the last window was closed, there was no log from `foreach()` method.

How to get the cache data?

I also found that, after `suppress()`, there was a probability of data accumulation. And whenever after `suppress()`, there was only one data stream to `foreach()`, the data was in a random window which didn't stream to `foreach()`. What happened to this process?

Comment: I want to know how do `suppress()`  judge if the window is closed. Is the next window's first data stream in `suppress()`?

Comment: You cannot. Windows are close on event-time, and event-time does not progress if no new input data arrives. Thus `suppress()` does  not emit anything.

Comment: I want to know how to handle the stream data. If I remove `suppress()`, all the intermediate result will be emitted. How to do accumulation of data in a window?

Comment: If you wan to accumulate the raw inputs, you aggregation function you pass in could do this, by putting each record into a `List` (or similar).

Comment: I think it is not a good way. I use kafka because kafka save data in disk, I don't want to save data in memory anymore. Using `List` might lose data when restarting the program.

Comment: That is not correct. If you use `KStream#aggregate()` and you `Aggregator` returns a `List`, you will also provide a corresponding `Serde` such that the data can be stored safely in a topic and won't get lost. (Note that spilling to disk is not a fault-tolerance mechanism, but fault-tolerance is achieved via change logging).

Comment: OK, and Thank you. Now I know what you mean.

Comment: I want to try another way. I found stream data didn't through the `suppress()`, because I create multiple partitions, each stream data accumulated by aggregation function will be re-partitioning. So, `suppress()` can not judge if the window was closed. How to solve this problem? :)

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. If data is repartitioned or not does not make a difference for `suppress()`. If you don't see output data, it implies that "stream time" (ie, event time) does not advance. This could happen if you stop sending data.